# How to include "build" directory when travis-ci builds and deploys npm module

Tags: javascript, git, npm, typescript, travis-ci

Currently I have Typescript module with `./src` dir in it

And travic-ci

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- 5.1.0

install:
- npm install
- npm install -g mocha
- npm install -g gulp
- npm install -g tsd

- tsd rate
- tsd install

script: gulp

after_success: npm test

deploy:
  provider: npm
  email: secret
  api_key:
    secure: secret
```

Gulp task generates files in to "./build" dir

The problem is that when it tries to deploy

```
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   build/
#
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

So it force me to build project locally and add it to github, and makes using of travis-ci as useless step

Answer (score 1):

Just resolved this problem with this steps:

1: Add `./build` dir to `.gitignore` file

```
build
typings
test/**/*.js
test/**/*.map
```

2: Create `.npmignore` to omit `.gitignore` rules (and I also put `.src` dir in it)

```
src
test
typings
```

Comment: Thanks for leaving your solution, exactly what I was looking for.